# is it better to use Html js DOM or Use CSS for responsive design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So i am trying to build mobile version of a Website and using CSS to change the styles when window's width is smaller than 400. basically website has 3 main sections upper, middle and bottom.i'have somehow made upper div adjust and displays on all devices very well but the middle and bottom div has to be completely removed and reconstructed. i have two options: get two pre-designed divs for each section(One for desktop and one for mobile).and hide one for mobile when page is loaded on desktop and vise versa. another option is creating all elements using javascript when page loads in mobile. which one is better and faster?

Comment: Firstly, note that your question is likely to be closed as it's pretty much a matter of opinion. Secondly, in my opinion, use CSS for responsive design. Always CSS. Unless you need behaviour which is impossible in CSS. Only then should you use JS (or redesign the behaviour so you can do it in CSS)

Comment: Definitely responsive and conditional css styling. As @RoryMcCrossan stated, you should reach out for js only in cases, that cannot be solved with css.

Comment: You should close this question as community is for solutions not for opinions, and take look on bootstrap it will help you

Comment: I wouldn't say it is about opinion. Using mainly css and js only for cases that cannot be done via css is a general answer with many logical reasons to back it up. Opinions that would say the other way around would be false. (For example blocking javascripts on the client side, performance of javascripts that would slow down the render, the fact, that changes via js woud require applying styles anyway and so on) - if it can be done and it makes sense to be done with CSS - use CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Suggest you go with CSS. If you wanna make mobile suitable application then CSS is great. We cant rely on JavaScript for the sake of design. You can use CSS+JS for any transformation thing like slides, any action or any event.